# Convert Mathtype formula (MS-Word) to LaTeX How import in Wikipedia articles?

Tags: msword, convert, wiki

I have same these formulas:

[image]

**I need import in my Wikipedia article.**

First I have convert these to Latex:

[image]

Returns:

[image]

Are:

(12.4)

`\[{\min _x}\quad \sum\limits_{i = 1}^N {\frac{{{{\left( {{P_i} - {P_0} + \beta {{\log }_{10}}{d_i}} \right)}^2}}}{{\sigma _i^2}}} \]`

and

(14.4)

`\(A = \begin{array}{*{20}{l}}{\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{l}}{ + 1}&0&0&0\\{ - 1}&0&0&0\\0&{ + 1}&0&0\\0&{ - 1}&0&0\\0&0&{ + 1}&0\\0&0&{ - 1}&0\\0&0&0&{ + 1}\\0&0&0&{ - 1}\end{array}} \right]}&{b = \begin{array}{*{20}{l}}{{P_{0L}}}\\{ - {P_{0H}}}\\{{\beta _L}}\\{ - {\beta _H}}\\{{x_L}}\\{ - xH}\\{yL}\\{ - yH}\end{array}}\end{array}\)`

Now I can't import in my Wikipedia article which views same as above original formulas.

When I import under `edit` link of a section then press `save changes` (put the above LaTeX within `<math>` and `</math>` tags, it remain complicated LaTeX format!

[image]

Excuse me, My original language is not English.

When Importing the (12.4) formula, converted automatically, then I have bounded within `<math>` and `</math>`

Any helps are appreciated.

Comment: The marked code in your screenshot is different to the provided code. There shouldn't be a space before the `_`.

Comment: @dexteritas, I have explained; `When Importing the (12.4) formula, converted automatically, then I have bounded within <math> and </math>`. Wikipedia automatically converts my code. So I have tried classic same text environment and so not converts my code to formula image.